# How much of the standard תורה service is done on שמחת תורה?

Tags: halacha, torah-service, simchat-torah

I've seen a number of *Simchas Tora* customs in Ashkenazic practice and/or prescribed by Ashkenazic prayer books. Specifically, I think I've seen both sides of each of the following dichotomies, sometimes in the same synagogue:

1. whether, after the nighttime *hakafos* and before the reading of the Torah, the congregation says "*B'rich shmeh*";
2. same question for daytime;
3. whether, after the nighttime *hakafos* and before the reading of the Torah, the leader/congregation says "*Sh'ma*", "*Echad Elokenu*", and "*Gad'lu*";
4. same question for daytime;
5. whether the person calling people to the Torah for the nighttime reading begins doing so with "*V'yaazor*" (as on a *Shabas* or holiday morning) or with "*V'sigale*" (as on an afternoon or weekday); and
6. whether *chatzi kadish* is recited immediately after the nighttime Torah reading (as it is mornings) or omitted (as it is afternoons).

Which, if any, of these questions have halachic authorities come down on one side or the other on? And which are/were documentedly in practice in which communities?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`1. whether, after the nighttime hakafos and before the reading of the Torah, the congregation says "B'rich shmeh";`

The [לוח דבר בעתו on page 242 (תשע"א)](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=51553&st=&pgnum=242) says: Yes.

`2. Same question for daytime;`

The לוח דבר בעתו says: Yes.

`3. whether, after the nighttime hakafos and before the reading of the Torah, the leader/congregation says "Sh'ma", "Echad Elokenu", and "Gad'lu";`

The לוח דבר בעתו says: Yes; Shma, Echad and Gad'lu etc. - all in the Rosh Hashana tune.

`4. same question for daytime;`

The לוח דבר בעתו says: Yes. Moreso: many have the custom to return all the Seforim to the Aaron HaKodesh and then one starts (over again) from Ata Hor'eta, VaYehi Binso'a, etc. like on any Yom Tov.

`5. whether the person calling people to the Torah for the nighttime reading begins doing so with "V'yaazor" (as on a Shabas or holiday morning) or with "V'sigale" (as on an afternoon or weekday); and`

The new Miller Machzor - מחזור השלם החדש בית תפילה - says: "V'yaazor".

The לוח ארץ ישראל and the  לוח ההלכות והמנהגים - זלזניק [page 103](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46120&st=&pgnum=103) say: Gad'lu and Al-HaKol. Which implies "V'yaazor".

`6. whether chatzi kadish is recited immediately after the nighttime Torah reading (as it is mornings) or omitted (as it is afternoons).`

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch says in [סימן קלח - דיני הושענא רבא ושמיני עצרת ושמחת](http://www.toratemetfreeware.com/online/f_00561.html#HtmpReportNum0137_L2) that chatzi kadish is recited immediately after the nighttime Torah reading.

> **סעיף ז':** 
>   יוֹם אַחֲרוֹן שֶל הֶחָג, שֶׁהוּא גַם כֵּן שְׁמִינִי עֲצֶרֶת, נִקְרָא שִׂמְחַת תּוֹרָה, לְפִי שֶׁמְּסַיְמִין בּוֹ אֶת הַתּוֹרָה וּשְׂמֵחִים בָּה. עַרְבִית, לְאַחַר הַתְּפִלָּה, עוֹשִׂין הַקָּפוֹת, וְאַחַר כָּךְ מַכְנִיסִין סִפְרֵי הַתּוֹרָה, וּמְשַׁיְרִין אֶחָד שֶׁקוֹרִין בּוֹ תְּלָתָא גַבְרֵי בְּפָרָשַׁת וְזֹאת הַבְּרָכָה. וְיֵשׁ מְקוֹמוֹת שֶׁנּוֹהֲגִין לִקְרוֹת בְפָרָשַׁת נְדָרִים. **אַחַר קְרִיאַת הַתּוֹרָה, אוֹמְרִים חֲצִי קַדִּישׁ**, וּמַכְנִיסִין אֶת סִפְרֵי הַתּוֹרָה וְאוֹמְרִים עָלֵינוּ. ‏

Comment: Seems more reasonable to recite a semi-full Kaddish (aka "kaddish tiskabel bli tiskabel") after leining like is commonly done after megillah on Purim and Tisha Bav eves. (This is especially true if there isn't a mourner around to effectively finish the service after aleinu; how can we end with a chatzi kaddish??)